# Setting up multiple services that can interact with one another WITHOUT docker-compose

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I'm setting up ElasticsSearch, Kibana and Logstash in single docker container.
Every tutorial that I've found used docker-compose to configure services, however due to corporate machine's limitations I can't use `docker-compose`. How do I configure services (namely ES, kibana and logstash) so that these build properly, can run within single container and talk to one another?

I've tested building ElasticSearch and Kibana within single docker container on my local machine by describing services in `docker-compose.yml` and that succeeded.

```
version: "2"

services:

  elasticsearch:
    image: elasticsearch:6.5.4
    ports:
      - "9200:9200"
    volumes:
      - ./esdata/:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data/

  kibana:
    image: kibana:6.5.4
    ports:
      - "5601:5601"
    environment:
      - ELASTICSEARCH_URL=http://elasticsearch:9200
```

The expected outcome would be to be able to build and run ES, Kibana and Logstash. These would be able to communicate with one another.
I currently know how to build these as completely separate containers, but don't know how to configure them to "cooperate" with one another **without**  `docker-compose`.

Comment: If you want to make all things in a single container go for a base debian/ubuntu image and create a bootstrap Dockerfile that installs and configures the ELK stack

Answer (score 2):

The only important detail is that the two containers need to be [on the same Docker network](https://docs.docker.com/network/bridge/).  Docker Compose automatically creates a network for you, but if you're not using that tool, you'll need to do it manually.

```sh
docker network create elk
docker run --net elk --name elasticsearch ...
docker run --net elk --name kibana \
  -e ELASTICSEARCH_URL=http://elasticsearch:9200 ...
```

Comment: Please correct me If I'm wrong. That means that I could approach this problem in two ways, either by putting everything in one container by getting ubuntu image and fetching everything for Elasticsearch and Kibana in one Dockerfile, or by creating separate images and separate containers that will share the same network, yes?

Comment: There are very good reasons to run different parts of the stack in different containers.  (You don’t want to restart Elasticsearch if you need to change some bit of Kibana configuration; you don’t necessarily want to replicate Kibana but you often do want to replicate Elasticsearch.) That’s doubly true if you’re happy with the prebuilt Docker Hub images.